# Html background image with Thymeleaf not appearing

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf, background-image

Obviously a newbie question but I'm having trouble getting the background image of my html to appear. I created a larger html but with this issue I simplified it to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
     <title>Chess Background</title>
     <style>
         body {
             background-image: url("/static/chess-background.jpeg");
             background-size: cover;
         }
     </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Welcome to the Chess Background Page</h1>
 <p>This page uses the chess-background.jpeg image as the background.</p>
 </body>
```

However, my background image is still not opening when I run it through the server locally through 8080. Note it does work when I simply open the document.

My controller is simple:

```
@Controller
public class ChessOpeningController {

@GetMapping (value = "/chessopenings")
public String getMethodName() {
    return "chessopeningsscreen1";
}
}
```

And when hovering over the image name in the html file with command it does allowing moving to the image.

I am using google chrome as a server and the structure of my maven project (extremely simple!) is shown below.

[image]

The resulting page:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up Chrome DevTools, you should see the requests the browser does. You will probably see a request to http://localhost:8080/static/chess-background.jpeg, but with a 404 error to indicate that this is not found on your server.

Spring Boot serves everything inside the `src/main/resources/static` folder at your server's root (`/`). This means that http://localhost:8080/static/chess-background.jpeg does not exist, but http://localhost:8080/chess-background.jpeg does.

So you need to change your CSS to be:

```
background-image: url("/chess-background.jpeg");
```

Comment: A very basic mistake for a guy very new to html! Thank you Wim.